# Add a price for minting an NFT

Tags: solidity, nft, payable, mint, price

I attempting to implement an NFT minter into my application, but want to set prices for minting an NFT. I'm using a smart contract template I found but haven't been able to figure out how to set prices. I've seen similar [solutions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110507/possible-to-set-a-minimum-price-to-mint-an-nft) for a smart contract that is like mine, but I can't seem to get prices to be set correctly.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
contract HiddenInPlainSight is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint public constant mintPrice = (4 ether/10);

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
    constructor() ERC721("Hidden In Plain Sight", "TLJ") {}
    function mint(string memory _uri) public payable {

        uint256 mintIndex = totalSupply();

        require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Provide more ETH");
        _safeMint(msg.sender, mintIndex);
        _setTokenURI(mintIndex, _uri);
    }
}
```

I added a require statement in the mint function but when I try to call the function, the transaction fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

probably you're not calling the `mint` function with the exact `value`,

the function is successful with `400000000` gwei or `400000000000000000` Wei (top left of the screenshot).
since `require(msg.value == mintPrice, "Provide more ETH");` and mintPrice is 0.4 eth (400000000000000000 wei).

by the way, you are overriding all the functions without changing the logic so you can remove it. example:

```
   function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
```

[image: Remix]

Comment: Thank you! I was overlooking that, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using WETH instead of using ETH native token for payment?

Minter has to allow WETH amount to this contract.

Check out my code below.

```
pragma solidity =0.8.14; // fix compiler version ( Preventing known bugs)
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol"; // IERC20 interface

contract HiddenInPlainSight is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint public constant mintPrice = (4 ether/10);

    // WETH address on mainnet
    address public constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
    constructor() ERC721("Hidden In Plain Sight", "TLJ") {}
    function mint(string memory _uri) public {

        uint256 mintIndex = totalSupply();

        // Minter have to wrap their ETH before or implement wrapping for them
        require(IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= mintPrice, "Not enough Wrapped ETH");
        
        // transfer WETH from msg.sender to this vault
        (bool success) = IERC20(WETH).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), mintPrice);
        require(success);
        
        _safeMint(msg.sender, mintIndex);
        _setTokenURI(mintIndex, _uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your mint function to accept ETH.

```
 function mint(string memory _uri) public payable {
        require(msg.value = _setMinimumValue, "Price too low!");
        uint256 mintIndex = totalSupply();

        // Minter have to wrap their ETH before or implement wrapping for them
        require(IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= mintPrice, "Not enough Wrapped ETH");
        
        // transfer WETH from msg.sender to this vault
        (bool success) = IERC20(WETH).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), mintPrice);
        require(success);
        
        _safeMint(msg.sender, mintIndex);
        _setTokenURI(mintIndex, _uri);
    }
```